# How can I make an array based on the cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Here are the browsers cookies:

```
console.log(document.cookie);
//=> name_instagram=true; name_googleplus=true;
```

And here is my code:

```
console.log(document.cookie.split(';').filter( (c) => c.startsWith(parts[1])).map( (d) => d.replace(/.*_(.*)=true/, "$1")));
//=> ["instagram"]
```

While the expected result is `["instagram", googleplus]`. How can I get that?

---

Currently as you see, just the last item in the cookie will be stored into the array as result value. What's wrong?

Comment: What's `parts[1]`? "name_"?

Comment: @Walk Yes, it's one item of an array which is `name`. i.e `var parts = ['id', 'name'];`

Comment: After your `startsWith` filter second item in array will be " name_googleplus=true;", note leading space, so it starts with " name_" instead of "name_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `startsWith` filter second item in array will be " name_googleplus=true;", note leading space, so it starts with " name_" instead of "name_". One way to fix it is using `trim()` to remove whitespaces.

```
console.log(document.cookie.split(';').filter( (c) => c.trim().startsWith('name_')).map( (d) => d.replace(/.*_(.*)=true/, "$1")));
```